# Flex BubbleChart fixed radius

Tags: apache-flex, charts, bubble-chart

I have a Flex `BubbleChart` and I want to set my bubble sizes explicitly. I don't want flex to take care of bubble sizes using `minRadius`, `maxRadius`. I need my bubbles to be rendered with exact size value.

Comment: Hey @KOsmos just wanted to let you know (although you might not have enough points yet to do this on StackOverflow) I think the best practice for answering your own on here is to actually post it as an answer and mark it correct for yourself.  Glad you got it figured out.

Answer (score 0):

Out of curiosity why is it you wouldn't just use the minRadius and maxRadius and set them to have the same value?  I dug through the code some and found the radii are used in the BubbleSeries.as in the updateDisplayList(in the 4.0.0 SDK this is on line 938) the conditional that sets up the radius on the objects to be drawn uses the minRadius and maxRadius as constraints so I don't see why this wouldn't achieve the goal.  Alternatively you can monkey patch BubbleSeries (or else just extend it and override the updateDisplayList mostly copying the one from the original source with modifications based on your explicitly set radius).

Comment: I must have used wrong words describing my problem. Bubbles need to have different values. But I want to assign the values myself.

Extending BubbleSeries is problematic because it contains lots of private (instead of protected) things.